# OS.js setup with node

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, os.js

I am trying to setup a os.js fronted with a socket.io backend in order to create a collaborative coding editor, could someone send a simple example of how to setup something like this with os.js. I find the documentation confusing, even a git repo of a basic project using os.js and websockets would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.